# Send a Instagram comment using Python with Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, instagram

I want to submit a comment using Python with Selenium. The comment box in Instagram web looks like this:

```
<textarea aria-label="Añade un comentario..." placeholder="Añade un comentario..." class="Ypffh" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" style="height: 18px;"></textarea>
```

My Python code:

```
coment_box = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("form textarea") 
coment_box.send_keys("Nice picture")
```

I tried to use the `find_by_xpath("here_xpath")` but it returns me an error saying that: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'send_keys'.

Comment: You can use the following CSS Selector: `.Ypffh`.

Comment: It says AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'send_keys'

Comment: So, you need to use `find_element_by_css_selector` instead.

Comment: if I use coment_box.find_element_by_css_selector(".Ypffh") and coment_box.send_keys("Hello") returns the error mentioned before

Comment: It is impossible, because `find_element_by_css_selector` will return 1 web element.

Comment: If I use      coment_box = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("Ypffh")
coment_box.send_keys("Hola")   it returns   NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"Ypffh"}
  (Session info: chrome=70.0.3538.102)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.44.609538 (b655c5a60b0b544917107a59d4153d4bf78e1b90),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)

Comment: You are using not correct CSS Selector. Look above what I sent.

Comment: I just checked, even if I use coment_box = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("textarea.Ypffh") it returns me and error. This is the picture I am trying to comment (https://www.instagram.com/p/BqsERghAdc2/)

Comment: Post your error, not picture :) Thanks.

Comment: This is the error-->NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"textarea.Ypffh"}
  (Session info: chrome=70.0.3538.102)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.44.609538 (b655c5a60b0b544917107a59d4153d4bf78e1b90),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)      IT APPEARS WHEN I USE--> coment_box = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("textarea.Ypffh")

Comment: are you sure you are logged into instagram when your web driver opens?

Comment: How can I be sure?

Comment: If you haven't done the login process in Selenium, you sure won't be. 
You can add the visibility to check it working and logging in, to be sure your program is working, before making it run at invisible mode

Comment: path = "C:\Users\Alejandro Dapena\Desktop\chromedriver.exe"#abrimos pestañas
driver = Chrome(executable_path= path)#abrimos pestañas
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=%2Fp%2F"+link_pic+"%2F&source=post_comment_input") #EL LINK_PIC ES EL IDENTIFICADOR UNICO DE LA FOTO
driver.maximize_window() #Maximizamos la pantalla  AND THEN I LOG IN INTO MY INSTAGRAM ACCOUNT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the following code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import ui
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


comment_box = ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "textarea.Ypffh")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", comment_box)
comment_box.send_keys("Hello!")
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: The comment box appears clicked though

Comment: It shows this error (but the comment box looks clicked)= StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=70.0.3538.102)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.44.609538 (b655c5a60b0b544917107a59d4153d4bf78e1b90),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)

Comment: @AlejandroDapena, try again my updated answer, please. Maybe, you need to update the version of your driver and browser.

Comment: WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot focus element
  (Session info: chrome=70.0.3538.102)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.44.609538 (b655c5a60b0b544917107a59d4153d4bf78e1b90),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)

Comment: I am using chromedriver.exe (idk if thats the best/its updated)

Comment: Same :( "Cannot focus element" but it stil looks  cliclked

Comment: comment_box.send_keys("Hello!")

Comment: One more time, please.

Comment: Exactly the same ...File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot focus element
  (Session info: chrome=70.0.3538.102)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.44.609538 (b655c5a60b0b544917107a59d4153d4bf78e1b90),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)

Comment: What if you will try the following expected condition: `EC.visibility_of_element_located` instead of `EC.element_to_be_clickable`?

Comment: Exactly the same, idk why, could it be something about my chrome drivers or something?

Comment: @AlejandroDapena, yes, please, check your version of Selenium, Chrome, chromedriver.

Comment: Same problem persists...I just redownloaded chromedriver, uptaded chrome (now I have version: 70.0.3538.102 (Build oficial) (64 bits)) and I pip installed Selenium yesterday so idk

Answer (score 6):

I clicked two times. it worked. I mean that you have to type bellow codes:(2 times write the click line)

```
commentArea = driver.find_element_by_class_name('Ypffh')
commentArea.click()
sleep(5)
commentArea = driver.find_element_by_class_name('Ypffh')
commentArea.click()
commentArea.send_keys("YOUR COMMENT HERE...")
```

Answer (score 2):

Was having this problem myself, although this post is old I found a solution so if anyone else is stuck here is what worked for me:

```
commentArea = driver.find_element_by_class_name('Ypffh')
commentArea.click()
commentArea = driver.find_element_by_class_name('Ypffh')
commentArea.send_keys("YOUR COMMENT HERE...")
```

I believe it has something to do with how instagram updates the textArea after you click on it, but this solution worked for me after searching and lots of trial and error :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import re
import time
import datetime
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import threading


def comment(browser):
    browser.get('https://www.instagram.com/')
    time.sleep(5)
    username = browser.find_element_by_name("username")
    username.send_keys('YOUR USERNAME')
    passw = browser.find_element_by_name("password")
    passw.send_keys('YOUR PASSWORD')
    passw.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    time.sleep(40)
    for i in range(5):
        browser.get('POST LINK')
        commentArea = browser.find_element_by_class_name('Ypffh')
        commentArea.click()
        time.sleep(5)
        commentArea = browser.find_element_by_class_name('Ypffh')
        commentArea.click()
        commentArea.send_keys("Using selenium to comment in burst of 5 ")
        commentArea.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        time.sleep(5)
    
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    browser1 = webdriver.Chrome()
    browser2 = webdriver.Chrome()
    threading.Thread(target=comment, args=[browser1]).start()
    threading.Thread(target=comment, args=[browser2]).start()
    # comment(browser)
```

This also has threading so you can post multiple comments at a time just enter your username and password and the link of post on which you want to comment